# Android Studio 1.3 - can't debug native

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am using the latest AS from the canary channel, and the ndk that goes with it.
I modified my Android project to suit, and my app (including JNI) builds and runs properly.

I have not (yet) allowed the tools to automatically handle building the JNI part.  Lots of special sauce in the existing makefiles, so that would be a lot of work.  So I don't have an `android.ndk` section in my build file.  I also have a single `gradle.build` file.

My debug build type looks like this:

```
android.buildTypes {
    debug {
        isMinifyEnabled = false
        proguardFiles += file('proguard-rules.txt')
        isDebuggable = true
        isJniDebuggable = true
    }
}
```

I added a native run configuration.  When I try to debug it, I get an exception like `LLDB server not found`.

If I switch the to gdb, I get a different exception.  Any thoughts?

A couple of JNI samples like `Teapot` and `hello-jni` are working fine.

Here is the LLDB exception:

```
LLDB server not found
java.lang.Throwable
    at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:115)
    at com.android.tools.ndk.run.lldb.AndroidLLDBDebuggerContext.launchLLDBServer(AndroidLLDBDebuggerContext.java:66)
    at com.android.tools.ndk.run.lldb.AndroidLLDBDebuggerContext.startServer(AndroidLLDBDebuggerContext.java:55)
    at com.android.tools.ndk.run.AndroidNativeDebugRunner$NativeDebugLauncher.launchDebug(AndroidNativeDebugRunner.java:109)
    at org.jetbrains.android.run.AndroidRunningState.launchDebug(AndroidRunningState.java:835)
    at org.jetbrains.android.run.AndroidRunningState.clientChanged(AndroidRunningState.java:814)
    at com.android.ddmlib.AndroidDebugBridge.clientChanged(AndroidDebugBridge.java:879)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Device.update(Device.java:721)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.update(Client.java:938)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleAppName.handleAPNM(HandleAppName.java:112)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleAppName.handleChunk(HandleAppName.java:65)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.callHandler(MonitorThread.java:414)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.processClientActivity(MonitorThread.java:322)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:263)
```

Comment: thanks for the formatting!

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a way to fix it?

Comment: I did not, but I haven't tried again since posting.  I suspect that @Rongfang is correct about needing to allow gradle to handle the building.

Comment: John - I got this working today using Android Studio 1.4, and the latest experimental Gradle plugin.  I've built most of the source into a static library, and linking the static library using ldFlags options in the android.ndk section

Comment: yes it also worked for me with 1.4!

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you need compile your C++ codes with gradle but not makefile. LLDB server will be generated with gradle automatically. Android studio didn't support any other external build systems(e.g. Makefile) yet.

Answer (score 0):

We have attach the debugger as java not as native. As for you have mentioned ndk it should use native. but any how try this method to avoid debugger detaching and app gets killed automatically.